# Powershell Compare Objects from multiple sources

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to build out a script to compare multiple CSV files and identify the delta in one master file. I think I'm close to having what I need but, I'm running into an issue when trying to set the value for the property on the master object.

I'm pulling in one CSV file (Sample) that has Computer Name, Location, IP, Active Directory, SCCM that I'm comparing to outputs from Active Directory (Compare) with the same information. I just want to update the first file with either a yes or no that the system is in Active Directory in the column called AD.

Here is the code that I have and need some guidance on fixing it:

```
$Sample = Import-Csv C:\Scripts\Sample_test_v1.csv
$Compare = Import-Csv C:\Scripts\Sample_AD_v1.csv


$Final = @()


foreach ($Samples in $Sample)
{
    $Final = New-Object System.Object
    $Final | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -name "Computer Name" -value $Samples.ComputerName
    $Final | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -name "IP Address" -value $Samples.IP
    $Final | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -name "Location" -value $Samples.Location

    If ($Samples.ComputerName -contains $compare)
    {$Final | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -name "Active Directory" -value "Yes"}
    Else
    {$Final | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -name "Active Directory" -value "Yes"}
}
```

Comment: Use `Select` with a calculated property: [Add Column to CSV Windows PowerShell](//stackoverflow.com/a/17022083)

Comment: turn it around in the if   if($compare.ComputerName.Contains($Samples.ComputerName))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out my problem with the below code which works now:

```
$Final = @()

$Samples = Import-Csv C:\Scripts\Sample_test_v1.csv
$Compare = Import-Csv C:\Scripts\Sample_AD_v1.csv

foreach ($Sample in $Samples)
{
    $Sys = New-Object System.Object
    $Sys | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -name "Computer Name" -value $Sample.ComputerName
    $Sys | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -name "IP Address" -value $Sample.IP
    $Sys | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -name "Location" -value $Sample.Location

    If ($compare.computername  -contains $Sample.ComputerName )
    {$Sys | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -name "Active Directory" -value "Yes"}
    Else
    { $Sys | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -name "Active Directory" -value "No" }
    $Final += $Sys
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With contains, you want the collection to come first. (Also changes Samples/Sample for clarity)

```
$Samples = Import-Csv C:\Scripts\Sample_test_v1.csv
$Compare = Import-Csv C:\Scripts\Sample_AD_v1.csv

$NewSamples = foreach ($Sample in $Samples) {
    If ($Compare.Computername -contains $Sample.ComputerName) {
        $Sample.AD = "Yes" 
    } Else {
        $Sample.AD =  "No" 
    }
    $Sample
 }

 $NewSamples | Export-Csv C:\Scripts\Sample_test_v1.new.csv -notype
```

Comment: I realized that you have to convert the CSV into a Object now just running into an issue with it not writing all the names to the object it only writes the last system name only